# Developer's iCloud not showing files

Tags: ios, icloud, iphone-developer-program

I created some text files and folders in my developer's iCloud account. Those files were created after migrating to iCloudDrive. When I access developer.icloud.com, I can't see those text files neither the folders. Why?

I can see my app's ubiquitycontainer (teamID~reversedomain~app) and its 'Documents' folder. Also I can see some old files I created before migrating to iCloudDrive.

Any ideas? I though that as a developer I'd have access to iCloudDrive through the web.
Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem: only 2 very old (1yr) docs are listed for me, and 2 new ones do not show up. I wonder if this service is deprecated? If so, what is the replacement service?